# Meaning of the preposition 'in' the sentence: "Her house lies in that direction."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions

What is the meaning of the preposition 'in' this below sentence? What relationship does it serve to indicate?

> Her house lies in that direction.

Is it idiomatic?

Answer (score 1):

*In* is an old word and has many uses.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in#:%7E:text=in%20preposition%20(ARRANGEMENT)) has **in *preposition* (ᴀʀʀᴀɴɢᴇᴍᴇɴᴛ)**

> used to show how things or people are arranged or divided:
>
> - We all sat down in a circle.
> - The desks were arranged in rows of ten.

It can be seen that "in that direction" has a similar sense: "We all sat down in that direction"; "The desks were laid out in that direction."

OED has **12b.** "Of form, shape, conformation, order", and shows this usage dates from Old English.

So, no: it's not idiomatic. *In* can be used to show how things are arranged in relationship to each other.

Comment: "Her house lies in that direction" is idiomatic. The meaning is "Her house is in that direction." It's about the location of the house, not about the arrangement of multiple objects. Your sentence about desks doesn't demonstrate that the OP sentence is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in) says:

## *in (preposition)*

***1a** —used as a function word to indicate inclusion, location, or position within limits*

- *in the lake*
- *wounded in the leg*
- *in the summer*

In your example, "in the north" indicates *location* or *position within limits*